# Python Getting second largest element in each row of matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-2.7, matrix, multidimensional-array

I begin with a correlation matrix, which means the i,jth entry would be the correlation between the ith element and the jth element(So the diagonals would be 1). I am trying to find the maximum correlation for each element with another element(not including itself since a list of 1's isn't helpful in my case).

```
1    0.7  0.4  0.1
0.7  1    0.3  0.2
0.4  0.3  1    0.5
0.1  0.2  0.5  1
```

Suppose I have the above matrix. I would like to have something like
 (max correlation, ith element, jth element). In the above matrix, I would like to get
`[(0.7, 0, 1), (0.7, 1, 0), (0.5, 2, 3), (0.5, 3, 2)]`
as a result.

What would be a good way to go about this?
I have the matrix as a pandas dataframe. The index and columns have the same name, say `[0, 1, 2, 3]` for now. Currently I've only thought of doing something like

```
D = {}
for i in df.columns:
    max = (0, 0, 0)
    for j in df.columns:
        if i==j:
           continue
        element = df.loc[i,j]
        if element > max[0]:
           max = (element, i, j)
    D[i] = max
```

Can this be done better/faster, and are there built in methods that can improve this?

Comment: Did you come up with a way to solve this? Do share what you have tried. It is important that you share and show effort on your part as thats how you learn the best and thats how it is supposed to be here on stackoverflow. A good way to go about this would be: Problem > your effort > question and other details. Research effort is mandatory. Good luck.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying. I've been thinking of looping through row by row(with nested `for` loops), and then checking to see which element is the second largest, but it seems to be somewhat inefficient.

Comment: Iterating through each column would also work since the matrix is symmetric. I'm trying not to sort it since I would like to get the original indices of the highest correlations.

Comment: Whatever you come up with, code it up and add it to your question. And yes nested for loops will be nasty as they are quadratic in nature. Try to divide your problem, try to come up with something recursive in nature. At the end if nothing else comes to your mind, Use the nested loops and add them to your question.

Comment: @sudo_dudo Do you see my code? I added it a while ago(before your comment I believe)

Comment: @sudo_dudo In addition, I don't believe recursion is faster than looping in general for python?

Comment: Not if you use the same logic: If you try to do the same thing same way, the only difference being using recursive calls instead of loops. What I meant when I asked you to try to come up with something recursive in nature is to think of dividing the problem up(Aka Divide and Conquer approach), which is not possible using loops. A fine example would be the Merge Sort algorithm which has O(nlogn), Anything iterative in nature is atleast O(n^2). And yes I did see that you added your code but only after adding my comment, thats why I upvoted your post.

Comment: Would only looping through the upper triangle be an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended using bits of the ideas, changing diagonal to some relatively small value like -1, of both answers(from Michael and kraskevich), but with a different method.

```
maxCors = dfFinalCor.apply(lambda x: (max(x), x.idxmax(), x.name)).tolist()
```

Gives me what I need :)
In addition, I feel like `apply` works well here. (I'm not sure why but I don't like to use zip unless I have to)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[1. ,  0.7,  0.4,  0.1],
              [0.7,  1. ,  0.3,  0.2],
              [0.4,  0.3,  1. ,  0.5],
              [0.1,  0.2,  0.5,  1. ]])
c -= np.eye(c.shape[0])  # remove the 1 on diagonal
result = np.array([[np.max(row), num_row, np.argmax(row)] for num_row, row in enumerate(c)])
```

From my understanding of what you mean with correlations, I'm assuming that you always have that value `1` on the diagonal of some symmetric real-valued quadratic correlation matrix `c` and that you don't care about this diagonal entry, so I'm just cancelling it out. What I do next is iterating over all the rows of the correlation matrix in the list comprehension. For every row I find the maximum and the index of the maximum with `np.max` and `np.argmax`, respectively, which gives the result you wanted. If you don't want to go with the array, you can instead use `result = [(np.max(row), num_row, np.argmax(row)) for num_row, row in enumerate(c)]` (or in light of the solution by @kraskevich `result = list(zip(np.max(c, axis=1), np.arange(c.shape[0]), np.argmax(c, axis=1)))`) which yields exactly your expected output.

Comment: I think it would be safer to set the values on the diagonal to something less than `-1`, not equal to `0` because the correlation coefficient can be negative.

Comment: I did not know that. In that case you're right. Anyway it might be better to work with a copy of the correlation matrix rather than overwriting the diagonal values.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can fill the diagonal with a value that is smaller than any correlation coefficient. There's a standard `numpy` function to do it:

```
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, -2.)
```

After that you just need to find the maximum value and its index in each column (a `DataFrame` has methods for computing both) and zip the results:

```
list(zip(df.max(), df.columns, df.idxmax()))
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, this solution iterates by column while as Michael's iterates by row? How do they compare performance-wise?

Comment: Yes, it iterates over the columns under the hood (it's impossible to find the maximum without seeing all elements). The best way to compare performance is to measure the time for both solutions on the data you need (I haven't done that).